# Including Laravel for an external script

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

So I'm going to use [Iron Worker](http://www.iron.io/worker) for my Project. Now, since I built my whole App around Eloquent, it would be convenient if I could include my whole Laravel Package, or at least the Eloquent bit. Could somebody point out to me how?

Comment: Just curious: What is "Iron Worker"? Any link?

Comment: iron.io, It is an cloud service that executes your pre uploaded script on demand. I only dislike it because it only supports one core. You can go out and buy 2 Digital Ocean droplets, put beanstalkd on them and listen for the queue and you'd have 2 cores for 10 bucks a month instead of the 24 bucks a month for 1 core which has Iron Worker.

Comment: Very interesting concept. Thank's!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i'am not mistaken. You can use `Composer` and Require `illuminate\database` component, look into README at https://github.com/illuminate/database.